# Dependency Injection, DDD what to unit test (&mock)?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design

I'm writing some test code for testing an ASP.NET MVC web application with Castle Windsor DI, Domain Driven Design (Application/Domain Services, Repository, Domain Model), NHibernate, and (most likely) MOQ for mocking. The possibilities of what can be tested are endless as basically everything can be tested.

Some possibilities are for example:

- Ensure Castle Windsor configuration will work (Test some conventions)
- Business logic (Inside an Entity, or Domain Service)
- Other things can be tested such as the controller actions etc.

There are quite a few things (so many layers - Controllers, Services, Repositories) which hardly seem worth any effort to test as they are quite simple in general.

With a smaller application it isn't very clear what could have the most benefit yet, but it will grow and the same patterns will be used on more complex applications.

For those with similar applications, what are you unit testing?

Comment: You haven't said what your application does ...  "similar applications" is too wooly. Someone coudl have the same architecture on a 2MLoc application but what they test will be dependent on their experience with all the functionality of that application. If you MVC web is only a few pages I would guess what you actually test would be wildy different.

Comment: The application itself is quite simple but it will be the basis of a quite broad application. Create/Edit/Update/Delete a lot of data with reporting etc. As for similar applications, I don't know where to draw the line. MVC, DI, DDD are probably the main factors, the actual framework might not be as important.

Comment: I'm still struggling to answer your question. In reality probably the only correct answer is to unit test / mock everything and get 100% code coverage. This would mean testing all inner workings of your application. Testing all the inner working would allow you to make sure that another developer hasn't bypassed your architecture. From my experience working with medium / large scale applications this is almost impossible and 100% code coverage is mostly thrown out the door when a client / stakeholder wants their feature added RIGHT NOW!

Answer (score 4):

Domain models and Application services are first citizens for unit tests if you don't have enough time or new to writing tests. These tests cover the most important part(application services for flow control and domain models for business rules). When I start to learn writing tests(don't know TDD at that time), they're the only part I test.

Then everything could be tested after adopting tdd. You'll need integration tests covering persistence, messaging and other integration points(mostly for testing configurations).

Answer (score 3):

The best answer for "what to unit test" question is ... everything - according to [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) :)

However, ensuring that properly configured components will work well together is rather a part of [Integration Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) or [Smoke Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing).

The suggested scenario in TDD is to write tests in parallel with the code, so both codes grow simultaneously. Your problem probably lies within the fact that you already have the code, and don't have the unit tests.  In such situation there are two possibilities:

1) Your components are well separated. Then you can write unit tests for public interface of each component, aiming to achieve high coverage (measured with some coverage tool).

2) Your components are tangled together. Then I'd suggest writing as much integration tests as you can, also aiming for high coverage. This will be harder than in case 1), so best to test most typical and crucial scenarios, and then refactor the code to loose some coupling, and then proceed with step 1).